# How can I conditionally find the earlier date after a given date in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to lookup between two dataframes for a series of IDs.

Each ID in lookup_df has a date it was published on, and I need to find the last date in ref_df, with respect to the lookup_df date.

In the below example, lookup_df ID 123 was published on 20200218, so of the dates in ref_df, I need to look only at those with ID 123, and find the last date before that, which would be 20200201.

I've tried various loops and cannot make this work, and the real database is over 600k rows, so I fear my current approach below of creating a temporary DF to then loop through would result in an impractical running time to complete this.

```py
ref_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,123,123,345,345,345],'version':['version1','version2','version3','version4','version5','version6'],
                       'date effective from':['20200101','20200201','20200301','20200401','20200501','20200601',]})
print(ref_df)

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[123,345],'date':['20200218','20200522']})
print(lookup_df)

for index, row in lookup_df.iterrows():
    temp_df = ref_df[ref_df['ID']==row['ID']]
    for index2, row2 in temp_df:
        #some code here to find the right date?!
```

Edit - apologise for being unable to show the tables directly, this is a function of my unfamiliarity with how to format my question - pointers appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the various suggestions below. I've tried several, and am getting an "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" error after ten or so iterations when i run it on the main database. Thanks in advance for any help in my understanding why this might be!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `last_valid_index()`:

```
idx = [ref_df.loc[ref_df['ID'] == value].last_valid_index() -
   1 for value in lookup_df['ID']]

print(ref_df.loc[idx])
```

EDIT: Removing the loops

```
mask = ref_df['ID'].isin(lookup_df['ID'])
new_df = ref_df[mask].groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-2])
print(new_df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this - I'll look at this as soon as I've tried the other suggested solution. Cheers!

Comment: I set this running on the main database an hour ago and it's still going, as the database has 600K rows. I don't suppose you know how I'd go about understanding how much progress it's making in that time, or shorten the duration and assign the answer directly to the lookup_df? Thanks again for your help, very much appreciated!!!

Comment: This has completed running, and appears to solve the problem completely!! Thank you very much for your help GhandiFloss - marked as solution. Thanks again for helping me solve my problem, and for adding to my python knowledge. You sir/madame, are a gentleman, and a scholar. A sincere thank you!!!

Comment: Hi Cheeseburger. Thanks for your kind comments. I have added an update if your look_up is large which should be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Change `date effective from` to `date` and try this:

```
for index, row in lookup_df.iterrows():
    result = ref_df.loc[(ref_df['ID'] == row['ID']) & (ref_df['date'] < row['date'])].iloc[-1,:].values[-1]
    print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
20200201
20200501
```

Comment: Thanks this, i'm experimenting with it now - looks like it does print the result. Seems like it may be quite slow, though this may just be the print function. do you know how I would do the operation more quickly, directly via dataframe or vectorisation, given the size of the database? Thanks again for your help, very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Additionally. and as per another solution below - I'm getting an error on this when I convert it to the main database: "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds". Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @Cheeseburger this mean that selected records for one of id's are missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the "latest" date from `lookup_df` using the following:

```py
latest = lookup_df[lambda x: x.ID == ID]['date'].iloc[0]
```

With this "latest" date, we can do another query on `ref_df` to obtain the desired result:

```py
result = ref_df[lambda x: x.ID == ID]\
    [lambda x: x['date effective from'] < date]\
    ['date effective from']\
    .iloc[-1]
```

To do the same for all IDs in `lookup_df`, wrap it in your codes as follows:

```
for _, row in lookup_df.iterrows():
    ID, date = row['ID', 'date']

    result = ref_df[lambda x: x.ID == ID]\
        [lambda x: x['date effective from'] < date]\
        ['date effective from']\
        .iloc[-1]
```

You don't need to iterate through all the rows in `ref_df`, make use of filters like the following:

```
df[<some condition here>]
```

or for example:

```py
df[df['idx'] > 3]
```

returns all rows in `df` that has the `idx` column greater than 3.

Comment: What is ID here ? This will throw an error as you have not defined it

Comment: The codes I've posted works only for a single ID. You can wrap my codes in your codes that iterate through the lookup_df. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Kelvin. I'm trying it now as I've had issues with the other answers. Can you explain how I can "make use of the filters like the following" which this answer so I don't need to iterate through the whole dataframe, and just assign it direct to another column on the dataframe instead? It feels like this would solve this problem entirely!!

Comment: Additionally - I'm getting an error on this when I convert it to the main database: "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds". Do you know why this might be?

Comment: The error happens when one of the IDs has no entry in `ref_df` where the `date effective from` is earlier than the `date` in `lookup_df`. As far as I can see, the answer by @GhandiFloss doesn't check for that. Unless the date that you want from `ref_df` is always the second last entry for any given ID, then that code will not give you the correct results.